# Permalink not working in Apache on Linux

Tags: permalinks

I was trying to set custom permalink but I am getting an error 404. Below are the settings I have tried:

1. I have gone through Settings > Permalinks > Custom and added `/%category%/%postname%/`.  It does not work.
2. Verified the contents of my .htacces file:

```
**# BEGIN WordPress**
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
**# END WordPress**
```

3. I have used a plugin.

However, I am still getting a 404 error page for the category that I have created. Can any one please help me?

Comment: can you share actual website url and example link?  
 try to click "save permalink" buttononce again,see if it works.

Comment: Please deactivate the plugin used if It works well

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the plugin you are using but the above permalink structure worked for me. This is the code I used.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please note I had to enable `mod_rewrite` module for this to work. After enabling, make sure you restart apache.